# ¿En Python django, si quiero que la regex detecte desde 6 caracteres al infinito, [\w-]{6,infinito} cuál es el cuantificador?

Tags: python, regex

```
url(r'^(?P<foo>[\w-]{6, })/$', view)
```

En django si quiero que la regex detecte desde 6 caracteres al infinito, `{6, infinito}`, ¿lo dejo en blanco, o cómo debo expresarlo?

De esta forma funciona pero no estoy seguro...

Answer (score 3):

**6 o más alfanuméricos, `_` y/o `-`**

```
^[-\w]{6,}$
```

- El cuantificador `{6,}` va sin espacios, sin nada, en el 2do parámetro.
- Es innecesario usar el grupo `(?P<foo>`...`)` en este caso, aunque no afecta el resultado.
- Los delimitadores como `/` no se usan en Python.
- Es una buena práctica incluir al guión `-` como primer caracter dentro de una clase de caracteres.

**Código**

```python
import re
# re es el módulo necesario para usar expresiones regulares
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

regex = r'^[-\w]{6,}$'
texto = 'abc123'

if re.search(regex, texto):
    print('Coincide')
else:
    print('No coincide')
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/2Z6AT1

Se puede llamar a:

- [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) que busca una coincidencia en cualquier lugar del string.

  ```python
  re.search(r'^[-\w]{6,}$', str)
  ```
- [re.fullmatch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) que busca sólo coincidencias con *todo* el string.

  ```python
  re.fullmatch(r'[-\w]{6,}', str)
  ```

---

**Otros cuantificadores**

```
  Cuant.   Descripción                             
 -------- ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  ?        1 o 0                                                             
  ??       0 o 1                                                             
  *        infinito a 0                                                      
  *?       0 a infinito                                                      
  +        infinito a 1                                                      
  +?       1 a infinito                                                      
  {n}      exactamente n repeticiones                                      
  {m,n}    hasta n repeticiones, mínimo m                         
  {m,n}?   mínimo m, hasta n repeticiones
  {m,}     entre m e infinitas repeticiones, cuantos más puedan coincidir    
  {m,}?    entre m e infinitas repeticiones, cuantas menos puedan coincidir
  {,n}     entre 0 y n repeticiones (sólo Python y Ruby)
```

Ejemplos:

```
  Cuant.    Descripción                             
 --------- --------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+       1 o más alfanuméricos (incluye "_"), cuantas más puedan coincidir
  \d{6}     exactamente 6 dígitos consecutivos
  x{3,6}    3 a 6 letras "x" consecutivas, cuantas más puedan coincidir
  @{2,5}?   2 a 5 arrobas consecutivas, cuantas menos puedan coincidir
```